# How can I reinterpret a RefMut<T> as a RefMut<U>

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a collection containing elements wrapped in `RefCell` that I borrow. I have a wrapper struct to make the api usable like so:

```rust
pub struct RefWrapper<'a, T> {
    inner: RefMut<'a, T>,
}

impl<T> Deref for RefWrapper<T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &T { &self.inner }
}

impl<T> DerefMut for RefWrapper<T> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T { &mut self.inner }
}
```

Foo and Bar have the same memory layout, so I can safely transmute between references of them, however  `RefMut` is not `repr(C)` and transmuting would be unsound for other reasons, so I can't safely transmute `RefWrapper<Foo>` into `RefWrapper<Bar>`. is there any way to convert from `RefWrapper<Foo>` to `RefWrapper<Bar>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can get a `&mut U` from a `&mut T`, then you can use [`RefMut::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefMut.html#method.map).

Here as a code example:

```rust
use std::cell::{RefCell, RefMut};

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bar {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}

fn convert_foo_to_bar(foo: &mut Foo) -> &mut Bar {
    unsafe { std::mem::transmute(foo) }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = RefCell::new(Foo { a: 42, b: 69 });

    {
        let foo_ref = foo.borrow_mut();
        let mut bar_ref = RefMut::map(foo_ref, convert_foo_to_bar);

        println!("{:?}", bar_ref);

        bar_ref.b = 420;
    }

    println!("{:?}", foo);
}
```

```
Bar { a: 42, b: 69 }
RefCell { value: Foo { a: 42, b: 420 } }
```

Be aware that his requires manually keeping the memory layout of `Foo` and `Bar` in sync. This will create very subtle and hard-to-find bugs if `Foo` and `Bar` are not 100% identical.

Of course one could generalize the concept by implementing `From`/`Into` for `&mut Foo` and `&mut Bar` instead of using `convert_foo_to_bar`. You can then use this trait to for your `RefWrapper` to convert between the two.